# Find minimum and maximum of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Below is my program.
Individually.... max and min functions works, but when I combine them using minmax, it is throwing the error.

```
max([H|T], M) :- max(T, H, M).

max([], M, M).
max([H|T], Y, M) :- H =< Y, max(T, Y, M).
max([H|T], Y, M) :- H > Y, max(T, H, M).
```

till here max code works individually

```
min([H|T], M) :- min(T, H, M).% \+ means "not"     //// min code starts

min([], M, M).
min([H|T], Y, M) :- H =< Y, min(T, H, M).
min([H|T], Y, M) :- H > Y, min(T, Y, M).      /// till here min code works

minmax([H|T],[max(T,H,M),min(T,H,M)]).     /// this is statetment with problem
```

Comment: In Prolog, predicates don't act like functions. So `[max(T, H, M), min(T, H, M)]` doesn't execute `min` and `max `as functions and return values.. You need: `minmax(List, Min, Max) :- min(List, Min), max(List, Max).`

Answer (score 0):

Now @lurker already addressed your error. I'm here just to showcase how library(aggregate) solves your need:

```
?- aggregate((min(C),max(C)),member(C,[3,6,2,6,1,9,2]),R).
R =  (1, 9).
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
list_min_max([H|T], Min, Max) :-
    list_min_max_(T, H, H, Min, Max).
    
list_min_max_([], Min, Max, Min, Max).
list_min_max_([H|T], Min0, Max0, Min, Max) :-
    min(H, Min0, Min1),
    max(H, Max0, Max1),
    list_min_max_(T, Min1, Max1, Min, Max).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- list_min_max([], Min, Max).
false.

?- list_min_max([5], Min, Max).
Min = Max, Max = 5.

?- list_min_max([6,7,6,3,6,7,345,1,25,8], Min, Max).
Min = 1,
Max = 345.
```